# AngularJS: intercepting the "paste" event breaks data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `AngularJS` application where I have a series of text input elements that are data bound to an underlying model with the `ng-model` directive:

```
<input type="text" myCustomDirective ng-model="cell.val" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

As you can see, I've also have custom directive on the input (`myCustomDirective`), the directive includes a `parser` used to process the text typed by the user and convert it to the underlying model value (and vice-versa, it also includes a `formatter` to format the model value to text).

This all works correctly. However, I have a requirement to implement a custom paste function that comes into play if the user pastes some data into the input. When that happens, I need to analyze the pasted data and depending on the result I might need to alter the data being pasted or even paste some data in another text input.
To achieve this, I've added an `ng-paste` directive like this:

```
<input type="text" myCustomDirective ng-model="cell.val" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
    ng-paste="contentPasted($event)">
```

Inside the handler, I do my processing and then if needed I "manually paste" data in the text inputs I want by doing this:

```
pasteEvent.preventDefault();
setTimeout(() => inputElement.focus(), 0);
setTimeout(() => inputElement.value = myData);
setTimeout(() => inputElement.blur(), 0);
```

The calls to `focus` and `blur` are my attempt to trigger the AngularJS model update... however, this doesn't work. The value in the text input changes correctly (and is also properly processed by the `myCustomDirective` formatters). But the underlying model does not update, and if I add a `ng-changed` directive to the element I see that it is not being called.

NOTE: you might ask why I don't just change the value in the model and let AngularJS update the inputs. The answer is: because I want the pasted text to be processed by the parsers implemented by the `myCustomDirective` directive, so I would like to simulate a "proper" paste into the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, shortly after writing the question I've found a workaround from another thread here on SO. Basically if I do this:

```
pasteEvent.preventDefault();
setTimeout(() => inputElement.focus(), 0);
setTimeout(() => inputElement.value = myData);
setTimeout(() => angular.element(inputElement).triggerHandler('input'));
setTimeout(() => inputElement.blur(), 0);
```

it works perfectly.

I'll leave the question open for a while in case someone has a cleaner / more "proper" solution.